# Grails controller values (map) to separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, variables, grails, gsp

I have checked a lot of forums, but I haven't got my answer.
So - I have a lot of JS code, so i keep it in separate .js file (not in .gsp view).
But now I have problems of accessing controller mapped values - I need them at my JS page, so I could generate my game field (based on values, that controller gives.
I have

```
def createGame(long id) {
 //getting my game info object...
 [gameInfo:gameInfo]      
}
```

And then I accessed them in view, like - `${gameInfo.playerName}` etc.
But how to get them to JS file? For example, player has chosen an object's color (that is JS generated).
One of examples could be `ball.fillStyle(${gameInfo.ballColor})`
But that, of course, is not working!
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the values using inline JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var gameInfo = ${gameInfo as JSON};
</script>
```

Comment: Am I putting this into my .gsp file? And how to access it's values? like - gameInfo.playerName?!

Comment: Yes, it will be in your GSP. Access it like your normally would. It's a JavaScript object when you do "as JSON". If you don't understand JavaScript objects, you need to do some reading.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Grails v2.3.11 - the quotes around string values were escaped even when I tried `${raw(foo as JSON)}`. I ended up using this instead: `var gameInfo = ${gameInfo.encodeAsJson()};`. EDIT: my variable was a `Map`.