# Access controller values (map) from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, grails, dictionary, gsp

I am saving all my data in `map` and now having trouble accessing them from a separate JS file.

On my (index) page I have 2 tables. The LHS table displays the list of available Instructions, and the RHS will display all the detail information of selected Instructions.

[image]

In other words, when the user clicks on the ID#1 on the LHS table, the RHS table will display all the Instructions info for ONLY that ID number.

I've added a `onclick` function to the ID in my LHS table. Code in `index.gsp`:

```
<tbody>
        <g:each in="${deliveryInstructions}">                           
            <tr>
                <td id="instruction_ID">
                    <a href="#" onclick="display_DI_details(${it.id})">${it.id}</a>
                </td>
                <td>${it.deliveryName}</td>
                <td>${it.bankName}</td>
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </tr>
        </g:each>
</tbody>
```

And in my `JS` file i have (got the JSON idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813416/1081016)):

```
function display_DI_details(id) {
    var deliveryID = id; 
    var deliveryInstructions = ${deliveryInstructions.encodeAsJson()};

    document.getElementById('diName').innerHTML = ${deliveryInstructions.deliveryName}
    document.getElementById('diID').innerHTML = ${deliveryInstructions.id}
    document.getElementById('fundingAccount').innerHTML = ${deliveryInstructions.fundingAccountNumber}
    ...
    ...
    ...
    document.getElementById('beneficiary').innerHTML = ${deliveryInstructions.beneficiary}
    document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = ${deliveryInstructions.comments}
}

document.getElementById("display-di-list").innerHTML = display_DI_details(id);
```

Again in `index.gsp` this is what I have for the RHS table...

```
<div id="display-di-list">
    <!-- <g:each in="${deliveryInstructions}"> -->
        <label>Delivery Name: <p class="receiptData" id="diName"></p></label>
        <label>Delivery ID: <p class="receiptData" id="diID"></p></label>
        <label>Funding Account: <p class="receiptData" id="fundingAccount"></p></label>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <label>Beneficiary: <p class="receiptData" id="beneficiary"></p></label>
        <label>Comments: <p class="receiptData" id="comments"></p></label>
    <!-- </g:each> -->
</div>
```

Finally in the `controller` file:

```
def index() {
    [deliveryInstructions: DeliveryInstruction.list()]
}
```

Now I am having trouble to connect few dots to finish this. In my `JS` file, how do I make it only grab the param values of the passed ID (lets say in this case the ID number is 1)? Thanks a lot for your help & time!!

Answer (score 1):

**Grails object into Javascript variable:**

```
var deliveryInstructions = ${deliveryInstructions.encodeAsJson()};
```

Produces invalid json for me, I believe the difference (if your way is working) has to do with the grails version used.
I had luck surround the `encodeAsJson` with a tag instructing grails to not escape the quotation marks:

```
<g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">
    var deliveryInstructions = ${deliveryInstructions.encodeAsJson()};
</g:applyCodec>
```

Disregard this if your way is already working, you can verify by looking at the produced html.

---

Within your function, if you have the `id` and the array of objects, `deliveryInstructions`, you can just use a javascript function to get the matching element within the array

```
var matchingDeliveryInstruction = deliveryInstructions.find(function(element){
    return element.id == id;
});
```

Now, just use the `matchingDeliveryInstruction` to set the right hand side's html:

```
document.getElementById('diName').innerHTML = matchingDeliveryInstruction.deliveryName;
document.getElementById('diID').innerHTML = matchingDeliveryInstruction.id;
...
etc.
```

I'm a big fan of using .js libraries for things like this, but depending on how much larger your project is it might be overkill.

---

Additional:
After looking at your question again, you mention a separate .js file.  The `${...}` will only work within your gsp.  You can leave your external .js file (a good practice) but you will need to have this within your gsp:

```
<script>
    var deliveryInstructions = ${deliveryInstructions.encodeAsJson()};
</script>
```

Based on what is generated, you may need to still wrap this with `<g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">`.  Now, this will create a global `deliveryInstructions` variable that will be accessible within your external file.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I am using  Grails 3.0.9 & Groovy 2.4.5. I am DEFINITELY doing something wrong, 'coz no matter what i'm trying, the `var deliveryInstructions` in JS file if not generating anything...therefore all the elements in the RHS table are empty. not sure what to do :<

Comment: What is the html look like where you have `var deliveryInstructions` declared?

Comment: it's blank, nothing is in it. I tried to assign the as `var deliveryInstructions = ${deliveryInstructions};`, `var deliveryInstructions = ${deliveryInstructions as JSON}`, `var deliveryInstructions = ${deliveryInstructions.encodeAsJson()}` and even ur way, but nothing prints out. the only error i get is `Unexpected token {` If i remove the `{` then it complains the `id is not defined` in `document.getElementById("display-di-list").innerHTML = display_DI_details(id);`

Comment: I updated my answer to include what I think is happening.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update, but unfortunately i can not make the variable global :( I think i'm going to do the try something different...handle all these from the controller somehow. But thank  you SO much for everything :)